# Python: Login into Adobe AEM via python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, aem

I am trying login into Adobe CQ5(AEM) author instance Python request module.

```
import requests
url = myauthor:port/content/login.html
payload = {'username':'username' ,'password' = 'password'}
r = requests.get(url,data=payload)
```

but I am unable to login. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That isn't the correct login url. What error are you getting here?

Comment: I reduces the context and when I give proper URL there , its still in same login page.

Comment: You need to use r.getHeader('Location') after checking for r.status_code == 302. You new location should be welcome page.

Comment: The default auth mechanism in AEM is form based (specific url) or you can use basic auth. Before getting into all that, it would help if we can understand your specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

AEM supports basic authintication.
The below code works for me :

```
  >>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
 >>> requests.get('http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/core/content/login.html', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'))
```

Response [200]

Comment: r.url still showing login.html as URL and it should redirect to welcome page instead

Comment: your requirement is not clear! In your initial post you said that login does not work and now seems you want something else.

Comment: Please understand the question. Whether u login or not still it provides 200 status code. But once login is successful it will move to next page after successful authentication.